# Meteor subscription is really slow

Tags: javascript, ios, meteor, react-native

Currently I have a pub/sub with Meteor. On my react-native app, I subscribe to a subscription.

The subscription only does something like `collection.find()` But the time I got the ready state for the subscription is really long. The collection only has 330 documents.

Here's my publication:

`Meteor.publish("clients", () => clients.find());`

Is it normal?

Thank you

Comment: Yes it is probably normal if you are not limiting record number and the fields that your publish method returns. Try adding a limit and then test it if its gonna get faster

Comment: But same if I only specify one field (name), the request is slow

Comment: And I need this because I want to do a live search ...

Comment: Please add some code to show your publish

Comment: I added the publish!

Comment: Try this and see if its gonna get faster. `clients.find({},{limit:10})`

Comment: Yes I already tried this, but the problem is I need to have access to all the collection because I do a search through all the collection. So the limit block me to do what I want to

Comment: If you want to do a search you need to change your query parameters dynamically and then return the limited result again to show client. Subscribing to 300+ records in a single run is always going to be slow because of the operation time and data transfer time.

Comment: So I need to have a subscription (with filter) recreated each time the text in my search bar change?

Comment: That is an option. Or if the data you are gonna make is not rapidly changing you can store the data in device sync with meteor database. There is a lot of options. You just need to figure out what is best for you.

Comment: Ok thanks! I would try something! :)

Comment: It really shouldn't be slow. Have you looked at the network trace to see what's going on? Look at the websocket messages, that's where subscription data goes.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample code that I have used.You can get and idea by looking at it.If you just publish your data, it will affect to your performance.

```
Meteor.publish('AllCustomers', function(search, hoid, options){

    // Prepare options
    options = _.extend({
        sort: {name: 1},
        skip: 0,
        limit: 10
    }, options);

    let query      = {}

    if ( search ) {
        let regex = new RegExp( search, 'i' );

        query = { 'headofficeId':hoid,
        $or: [
        { name: regex },
        { telNo: regex }
        ]
    };

    }else{
       query = {'headofficeId':hoid};
    }

return Customers.find( query, options );
});
```

Comment: Thanks! And how do you handle the subscription on the client?

Comment: this.subscribe('AllCustomers'{set parameters here});

Comment: but do you subscribe everytime the user type something?